# How to downgrade geth version?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testrpc, embark

I'm having this error, which I doubt is because of the newer version of geth & the project being more than a year old.

I'm unable to downgrde geth anything below 1.5.9, I'm using a mac.

Also, I'm using testrpc & not exactly geth, could this be some other issue?

[image: Error]

Comment: this is not `geth`, `geth` is written in golang and you have javascript here